# How can I make Azure instances use as little RAM as AWS?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, cloud-computing, azure

I'm comparing the small instances of Azure, Amazon and Rackspace, and noticed that the Amazon configuration appears to use less RAM than Azure.  Can anyone explain why this is?

Would it be true to say that the OS configuration of Amazon is more efficient than MSFT Azure?  ... or is Azure configured out of the box for a special purpose?

**Image of Task Manager in Amazon**

(Note: Usage only increases to 672 MB when identical roles and features are installed)

[image]

**Image of Task Manager in Azure**

[image]

I didn't bother with Rackspace since the comparable RAM is ~700MB less than the other offerings and the OS/RAM usage isn't configured as efficient as either Amazon or Azure.

Comment: 36 Processes vs 58 on Azure, you may want to look into that.

Comment: Windows is intentionally tuned to leave as little RAM free as possible. Free memory is opportunity forever wasted. It's not like if you use less today you can use more tomorrow.

Comment: Click on the "Resource Monitor" button to get details about the memory usage of your running processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshots provided I would take a look at why you have more processes running on the Azure instance versus the Amazon instance.  You have more process, threads and handles open so theoretically the OS is doing more.  Figure that out and you may find the differences.